# How to put a fraction in simplest form, such as $140/255$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Given the fraction
$$\dfrac{140}{255}$$

How do I find a common factor so it can be easily simplified? I have already tried $2$, $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Now try 5.$\,\,$

Comment: not clear what you're asking but there are many checks for common factors - if they're even try two, if the digits sum to a multiple of 3 then try 3, if the last two digits go into 4 then try 4, if the last digit is a 5 or 0 then try 5...

Comment: "Common denominators" refers to a problem with multiple fractions. (A single fraction has only one denominator.) I see one fraction in the question; where are the other(s)?

Comment: Integers with decimal units digit $\,0\,$ or $\,5\,$ are divisible by $\,5.\,$ In any case you can always used the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd.

Answer (score 6):

You have the right idea.  Let's see if we can get you to the answer.

You've tried $2, 3, 4$.  It appears that you're trying to get the fraction in lowest terms.

Some basic [divisibility rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) might help.  In this way you can inspect the numbers (fairly) quickly to see whether or not they evenly divide the number:

- A number is divisible by $2$ if the rightmost digit is even ($2,4,6,8,0$).  So, the numerator is divisible by $2$, but the denominator isn't.
- A number is divisible by $3$ if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.  So, $140$ is not, because $1+4+0 = 5$ is not divisible by $3$, but the denominator is, because $2+5+5 = 12$ is divisible by $3$.
- A number is divisible by $4$ if it is *twice* divisible by $2$.  The numerator is, but the denominator is not.
- A number is divisible by $5$ if its rightmost digit is $5$ or $0$.

AHA!  This looks promising:

$$\frac{140}{255} = \frac{5 \cdot 28}{5 \cdot 51} = \frac{28}{51}.$$

Are we done?  Well, we can start again with this fraction.  If you run through the rules above, we find that none of $2,3,4,5$ divide both the numerator and denominator.

And with that, we're done.  Why?  Because you don't need to try any numbers that are bigger than *either* the square root of the numerator, or the square root of the denominator.  Since $\sqrt{28} < 6$, we didn't need to test any numbers larger than $5$.

I'll also point out that we didn't need to test the number $4$.  Why not?  Because $2$ divides $4$.  Since the denominator wasn't divisible by $2$, it won't be divisible by $4$, either, so there's no need to test it.

We can extend this a bit and say that we only need to test numbers that have exactly two factors: itself and $1$.  These are called [prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Any natural number greater than $2$ can be written as the product of one or more prime numbers.  The so-called [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of the original numerator is $140 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$; for the denominator, it's $255 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17$.  Notice that the only common factor is one $5$.  This is the [greatest common factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).  Dividing both numerator and denominator by the greatest common factor will get the fraction in lowest terms.  This is why we were done with this problem after we divided by $5$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Like the man who invented 5-Up and 6-Up, you stopped one number short of success. Of $140$ and $255$, only the former is divisible by $2$ and by $4$, and only the latter is divisible by $3$, but both are divisible by $5$. This should immediately lead to the answer: $\frac{28}{51}$.

How can you find a common factor? If none immediately suggest themselves, you can try getting the prime factorization of the numerator and the denominator, and this works reasonably fine for small numbers like $140$ and $255$.

For anything much bigger than that, you might need the Euclidean GCD algorithm. Take for example $$\frac{279244}{508623}.$$ Your computer can immediately see the common factor, but without a computer (e.g., on a test for which you're only allowed a basic calculator), you don't want to spend too much time on trial division. So:

- $508623 = 1 \times 279244 + 229379$
- $279244 = 1 \times 229379 + 49865$
- $229379 = 4 \times 49865 + 29919$
- $49865 = 1 \times 29919 + 19946$
- $29919 = 1 \times 19946 + 9973$
- $19946 = 2 \times 9973 + 0$

On second thought, I hope you don't get a test problem where the GDC is a $4$-digit prime.

Answer (score 0):

To put a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ in simplest form, the most straightforward way usually comes from knowing $\gcd(a, b)$. In the case of $\frac{140}{255}$, we have $\gcd(140, 255) = 5$. Divide the numerator by 5 and divide the denominator by 5 to obtain $$\frac{28}{51}.$$ To verify the answer, check that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.